I cannot login using test.salesforce.com doesn't work despite it is not forbidden in domain settings
Often after sandbox refresh, I am not able to login using test.salesforce.com even though it is not forbidden in domain settings.

What might be the reason?
Login history is empty for the user

The error says

However, if I use my domain, I can login successfully

It seems that this is the behaviour described by salesforce. It might take up to 48 hours until it is possible.
On the help page it stays the following:

After a sandbox is created or refreshed, it can take 24–48 hours before you're able to log in using https://test.salesforce.com. During this period, access your sandbox via its My Domain login URL.

Link:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385817&type=1
From my personal experiences - it takes near 15 minutes until it is available or until you log in at least once via the my domain.

thanks, I didn't know this...

I suggest you to update your trailhead profile link in description of sse user and update text, I bet you are not trainee SF developer anymore
